# SQL backup/restore slow, from SQL server 2008 to SQL server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, database-backups, database-restore

Thanks for your time!

I am currently scripting an unattended SQL backup and restore of a database. The source database is a SQL server 2008 and the destination database is a SQL server 2012.

Doing it manually this is what happens:

Taking the backup file (.bak) is fast. When restoring the database to the SQL server 2012 the restore process goes up to 100% and then uses an additional 15 minutes before finishing. I have been searching the web and found out that this additional time is the undo/redo phases and that you can skip the redo phase. Doing this, did not speed up the process.

The funny thing is that if I create an empty database and set the compatibility mode to SQL server 2008 and restore it to this database, then the process is fast. Unfortunately I cannot restore with compatibility mode on unless creating the database beforehand.

Does anybody have any ideas to solutions that could work? Either restoring with compatibility mode on (As far as I know thats not possible) or fixing the database such that it will not be a problem?

Thanks in advance!

Regards
Magnus D. Frank

Comment: might be better suited to http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I doubt that setting the compat mode of the database you *overwrite* does anything. It is not preserved when restoring. Are you sure your test tested *only* that setting? Any other changes? You were restoring to the same instance in both tests right?

Comment: Well, as I said. I created a new database and restored to this specifik database with compatibility mode set to 2008 rather than 2012. So if restoring to an existing database is different from a normal restore, then some settings where different, but if not, then the compat. mode was the only setting changed.

And yes I restored to the same instance in both tests.

Comment: Is the empty database you create manually on a different set of drives to the one that is created by the backup?  That could account for a difference in speed.

Comment: It is empty, but on same drive.

Comment: Did you restore to different locations each time? Different drives or folders?

Comment: I will be running some test now. I will use same drive, same folders. I will time it and I will report back the results.

Comment: It was because of the log files being 10GB big. I shrinked the files and can do a backup/restore in ~10 secs. Sorry for wasting your time